# rbenv init の exit code がエラー扱い

Tags: rbenv, itamae

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation
公式 rbenv のインストール手順を 
itamae という構成管理ツールでレシピ化しているところなのですが

```
execute 'rbenv init' do 
  user "ssm-user"
end
```

の部分が

```
ERROR :       stdout | # Load rbenv automatically by appending
ERROR :       stdout | # the following to your profile:
ERROR :       stdout |
ERROR :       stdout | eval "$(rbenv init -)"
ERROR :       stdout |
ERROR :       Command `sudo -H -u ssm-user -- /bin/sh -c cd\ \~ssm-user\ \;\ /home/ssm-user/.rbenv/bin/rbenv\ init` failed. (exit status: 1)
ERROR :     execute[/home/ssm-user/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init] Failed.
```

exit status: 1 でエラー扱いになってしまいます
stdout の内容を見るに正常に動いてるみたいなのですが
どうすればレシピが止まるのを回避できるでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rbenv init は、 execute するのではなく、それを /etc/profile などに記述して、毎回ログインシェルの起動時に読み込むようにする必要があります。

個人的には、自前で書くのではなく、 https://github.com/k0kubun/itamae-plugin-recipe-rbenv を利用する方がずっと楽だし早いと思っています。

Comment: すでにレシピがあるのですね。使わせていただきます！